# How do i capture the search entry typed in google.com using a web extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does google search box have a fixed id which I can access via the inspect option on the browser so that I can extract the contents typed in it via a custom web extension.

content.js

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () =>{

        const searchInput = document.querySelector('input[name="q"][type="text"]');

    //const searchInput = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
    searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        // Extract the search text from the input element
        const extractedText = searchInput.value;
        // Store the extracted text in a secure location (e.g., browser storage)
        // ...
        chrome.storage.local.set({ ['KEY_SAVED_TEXT']: extractedText }, () => {
            console.log('Text saved successfully!');
        });

      }
    });

    });
```

It seems the code is not extracting any content to be stored in the chrome storage api. How do i fix this so that I can display the search content in a popup, when I click on the extension symbol in the extension bar.

Comment: The textarea in the search box has an id, but I don't know, if that one is set or can change.